# PHP: Bold lastname in autosuggest too

Tags: php

```
    $queryString = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['queryString']);
list($firstname, $lastname) = array_map('ucfirst', explode(' ', $queryString, 2));
$query = mysql_query("SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, users.id 
FROM users INNER JOIN users_friends ON users.id=users_friends.uID
WHERE bID=$USER AND type = '$type' AND (users.firstname LIKE '%$queryString%' OR users.lastname LIKE '%$queryString%') 
LIMIT 10;
");
while ($result = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
$re_fname='<b>'.$firstname.'</b>'; 
$re_lname='<b>'.$lastname.'</b>';
$final_fname = str_ireplace($firstname, $re_fname, $result->firstname);
$final_lname = str_ireplace($lastname, $re_lname, $result->lastname);
             echo $final_fname. ' ';
             echo $final_lname.' ';
}
```

This is my code for the searching part in my autosuggest dropdown..

I want what youve searched get bold text. Example if you type "Meg" then the "Meg" in Megan, is bold.

This does it fine without any problems. But the lastname doesn't work.

When I type "Fo" or "Fox" or "F",(Megan Fox) it doesn't get bold in the lastname. Why doesn't this work, and how can i fix this? Is it because $lastname is the text after the space, but I even tried "Megan F" or the full "Megan fox" only Megan gets bold, not "Fox".

Comment: What's the resulting HTML and JavaScript that may be touching this?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
<?php
list($firstname, $lastname) = array_map('ucfirst', explode(' ', 'meg f'/*hardcoded*/, 2));
if(!$lastname)
 $lastname = $firstname;
$re_fname='<b>'.$firstname.'</b>'; 
$re_lname='<b>'.$lastname.'</b>';
$final_fname = str_ireplace($firstname, $re_fname, 'Megan'/*hardcoded*/);
$final_lname = str_ireplace($lastname, $re_lname, 'Fox'/*hardcoded*/);
echo $final_fname. ' ';
echo $final_lname;
?>
```

And yes, if you don't have a space you will get a value only for `$firstname`.

Also you should consider regular expressions for matching case insensitive but replacing case sensitive.

Comment: Still havn't found out why it won't work with me. If I use if(!$lastname)
 $lastname = $firstname; and then type, "Fo" then it bold like it should, but not both (both first AND lastname)

Comment: You want to say that you copy pasted my sample script and it does not output: *Meg*an *F*ox ?